# Help needed with understanding of simple probabilities

Tags: probability

I'm sitting with some simple probability problems and I would love to ask some questions to understand what I'm missing.
Specifically I'm trying to understand a series of assignments I've been given about coin tosses coming up heads or sums of dies tossed.

A coin is tossed three times,

1. what's the probability of getting heads in all throws?
2. What's the probability of at least one toss of the coin being heads?
3. what's the probability of exactly toss of the coin being heads?

By making a counting tree I could figure the first one to be 1/8 and the third one to be 3/8. But I lack the understanding of how to do the second one at all and also how to make a calculation for all of them.
I could figure out that the probability function for this was 1/2^n. But that's about it.

I also need a bit of understanding onto situations with sums. A given example is "what's the probability that the sum of a toss of three dies, ends up as 10?" I honestly have no idea how to deal with this.
My instinct tells me to make a stochastic variable representing the sum, so 1/6*1/6*1/6, but this doesn't make sense to me, as I know I'd also have to account for the events where the dies don't reach my ideal example of 4,3,3. Another example would be 7,2,1. So it can't be how I proposed it to be.

Any help is highly valued.

Comment: For this kind of probabilities, the most simple approach is to count the number of possible issues, and to look at how many of those correspond to the event you're looking for. 
For three coins in a row, you have 8 cases: HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT. Note that the order matters (HHT is not HTH). 
For the first case, you see that the probability is 1/8, since, on the 8 configurations, only HHH corresponds to what you want. Can you make a similar argument for the second one ?

Comment: Also I believe a word is lacking in your point 3.

Comment: Thank you very much Gâteau Gallois.
This was very helpful.

Do you have any advice regarding situations with sums, such as sums of dice being 10?

Comment: when it's a small sum (e.g. the three dices), you can again write all the issues and look at the one corresponding best to your case. For instance: for three dices, you have 6*6*6 issues.  How many of them lead to 10 ? 
Start from the first dice and be systematic: when it gives 1, the issues are:
1-3-6; 1-4-5, 1-5-4, 1-6-3.
Do the same when the first dice starts with 2, 3 and so on... 
You will end up with N issues (be careful, here again the order does matter, you should count 1-3-6 AND 1-6-3) corresponding to a total sum 10. The answer you're looking for is then simply $\frac{N}{6^3}$